# Choose two basis $A,B$ from $\mathbb{R}^3$ such that $T^{A}_{B}(F)=\left(\begin{smallmatrix}1&0&0\\1&1&0\\0&0&0\end{smallmatrix}\right)$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, vectors, linear-transformations

> $M= \begin{pmatrix}  1 & 0 & 1\\   2 & 1 & 1\\ 
> -1 & 1 & -2 \end{pmatrix}$ is a real matrix and $F: \left\{\begin{matrix} \mathbb{R}^{3} \mapsto \mathbb{R}^{3} \\  x
> \mapsto M \cdot x \end{matrix}\right.$ is the linear mapping given by
>   $M$
>
> Choose two basis $A= (v_{1},v_{2},v_{3})$ and $B= (w_{1},w_{2},w_{3})$
>   from $\mathbb{R}^3$ such that
>   $T^{A}_{B}(F)=\begin{pmatrix}1&0&0\\1&1&0\\0&0&0\end{pmatrix}$

I know how to do it the other way around, I mean when basis are given and I'm supposed to determine the tansformation matrix. But how to solve it this way? I found that task on the internet and I hope the things given above are even enough. I could try to write a solution but I barely have an idea :(

Comment: If you know how to determine the transformation matrix, you could write the transformation formula in general, for unknown basis with coefficients $b_{íj}$ and then trying to compute these coefficients.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that you can choose both bases, which is rather uncommon for maps from a vector space to itself (where one usually would want to use the same basis twice). Given that you have this freedom, the only constraint that might form an obstruction to your task is the rank of the matrix (which will be the same whatever bases you use to express things on). It is not hard to see that $A$ has rank$~2$, and so has the prescribed form $T^A_B(F)$. In order to get a last column entirely zero, you must choose $v_3\in\ker(F)$, and nonzero. With this done, choose any $v_1,v_2$ to complete to a basis. Now the first column column of $T^A_B(F)$ is saying $T(v_1)=w_1+w_2$ and the second is saying $T(v_2)=w_2$. It is not hard to solve $w_1,w_2$ from this, and you can choose $w_3$ in any way to complete to a basis. For another pair of bases, just make other choices.

Comment: Thank you very much! If I solved that task and editted my answer later, could you please take a look at it?

Comment: You can answer your own question (rather than edit it) using my suggestions; that is fine, and I'll look at it.

Comment: A question before I start, $\text{ker}(F)$, so I have to calculate the kernel of matrix $M$, right?

Comment: Yes, you need to do that.

Comment: Sorry for several questions  already, but how "choose any $v_1,v_2$ to complete to a basis"? I have that  $\text{ker}(F)= \left\{\begin{pmatrix}
-z\\ 
z\\ 
z
\end{pmatrix} \mid z \in \mathbb{R}\right\}$, I set $z=1$ and get $v_3= \begin{pmatrix}
-1\\ 
1\\ 
1
\end{pmatrix}$.

Comment: Do you know about the [extension from an independent set to a basis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basis_(linear_algebra)#Extending_to_a_basis)? Just take any basis of your space (for instance the standard basis), and keep adding elements from it to your independent set (initially in single vector in your case) provided the result is still linearly independent (if not just drop that vector).

Comment: Ok never mind I cannot do it I thought it was easy but it isn't. But thank you anyway for your answer and time. If it's asked in the exam, we will get low points on it anyway even though it seems to require a lot time to solve it...

Comment: Not a lot of time. You already had $v_3=(-1,1,1)$. Complete with $v_1=(1,0,0),v_2=(0,1,0)$ from a standard basis. Get $w_2=F(v_2)=(0,1,1)$ and then $w_1=(w_1+w_2)-w_2=F(v_1)-F(v_2) = (1,2,-1)-(0,1,1)=(1,1,-2)$ and complete with (for instance) $w_3=(1,0,0)$. That was only long because I needed to keyboard it correctly.

Comment: I cannot believe it but now I really understood how its done. I could even solve another task and everything was correct. Thank you so much again. I made another topic another day ago and I put a bounty on it (200). I'd like to give you the bounty so it's not wasted. So maybe just write an answer there saying some words (linking to this topic which helped me, or something like that). But don't waste your time writing another complete answer for me because I really understood because of you now! :)